# How to run MapReduce script through Hortonworks Sandbox in Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-sandbox

I have Hortonworks Sandbox and ran the command:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222;
```

After logging in, I would like to run MapReduce on 2 HDFS files RatinsBreakdown.py and u.data located under Documents like I did here:

```
python RatingsBreakdown.py -r hadoop hdfs:///user/[username]/u.data --hadoop-streaming-jar /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar
```

How can I adjust the command above to run through the Hadoop cluster?

```
[root@sandbox ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

If `RatingsBreakdown.py` is a `mrjob` process, then that command you've shown does everything you want. You can open the YARN UI to verify the process ran in the cluster.

Otherwise, [the documentation on Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) should point you at the correct location